# change the value of vector based on the string of its name

Tags: r, vector

users,

Imagine I have 3 vectors:

```
proc1<-0  
proc2<-0  
cpd<-c("proc1","proc2")
```

How can I change the value of proc1 to 1, based on vector cpd only? 
I tried with `as.factor(cpd[1])<-1`, but it produces an error.

Any idea how could I achieve that?

qill

Comment: You could do `eval(substitute(x <- 1, list(x = as.name(cpd[1])))); proc1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `assign`:

```
assign(cpd[1], 1)
print(proc1)
# [1] 1
```

EDIT: To get a value, you can use `get()`:

```
proc1 = get(cpd[1])
```

Comment: Thank you @Fernando... However, is it also possible to first get the value of proc1, and add it by 1 before store it back to proc1? 

assuming we still do that by accessing cpd[1] only....